# Numering of longtable and normal table

Tags: tables, floats, longtable

I have two tables: one normal table, and one longtable.
The normal table comes first in my code and referencing, and the longtable comes after. However, the longtable appears first than the table. How can I change this?

I want the normal table to appear smoothly first, and then the longtable.

Compilable code: https://codeshare.io/aVdxY8

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
%% To allow tables collumns auto newline
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}    % Beautiful simple tables
\usepackage{paralist}    % To enable customizble enumerates
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox,tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}



\subsubsection{Linear variability}

Significant results obtained when testing the linear variability metrics are presented in Table \ref{table:linear_var_POAF_results}. Briefly, the variability in both time and morphological features were significantly different between POAF and controls far away from the arrhythmia (at least 18 hours away), while only variability in P-wave time features were significant as the arrhythmia onset got closer. The POAF group had higher median variability for all the presented timestamps, and showed increasing variability (slope) in all timestamps except 18 hours before the arrhythmia onset. In contrast, controls presented decreasing variability in the majority of variability regression slope results. The PQ interval (duration and level) was the only feature which had metrics significant after correction for multiple comparisons at 6 and 48 hours before the arrhythmia onset.

\begin{table}[!htp]
    \caption[Significant results obtained when using linear variability metrics to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.]{Significant results (uncorrected $p<0.01$) obtained when using the linear variability metrics. Results significant after correction for multiple corrections (corrected $p<0.05$) are shaded in grey. The median value (and the first/ third quartiles) of each group are presented.}
    \label{table:linear_var_POAF_results}
    \small
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
            \hline
            \textbf{Metrics}                                                    & \textbf{Controls}                 & \textbf{POAF}                    & \textbf{P-value} & \textbf{AUC} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})}  \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}        & 4.8$\times10^{-2}$ (4.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.7$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.8$\times10^{-2}$ (5.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 7.6$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\

            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}       & 1.5$\times10^{-2}$ (1.2$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.2$\times10^{-2}$ (2.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize} & 5.5$\times10^{-2}$ (4.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.2$\times10^{-2}$ (5.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}        & 5.1$\times10^{-2}$ (4.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.6$\times10^{-2}$ (5.7$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 1.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}       & 4.0$\times10^{-2}$ (3.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.5$\times10^{-2}$ (4.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 7.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}      & 1.7$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 3.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.5$\times10^{-2}$ (2.2$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.6$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}      & 1.7$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.8$\times10^{-2}$ (1.9$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 8.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline  
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}   & 24.0 (16.0 / 30.0)             & 28.0 (24.0 / 37.0)             & 5.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize} & 5.9$\times10^{-2}$ (5.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.1$\times10^{-2}$ (6.1$\times10^{-2}$ / 9.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}                & 38.0 (32.0 / 44.0)             & 44.0 (36.0 / 58.0)             & 5.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\

            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}        & 5.6$\times10^{-2}$ (4.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.9$\times10^{-2}$ (6.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 9.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.9$\times10^{-4}$        & 0.80       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}             & 8.0 (8.0 / 12.0)               & 16.0 (11.0 / 21.0)             & 1.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}       & 4.8$\times10^{-2}$ (3.7$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.9$\times10^{-2}$ (4.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.7$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}     & 1.5$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.3$\times10^{-2}$ (1.9$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.5$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(Q\textsubscript{on amp.})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                       & -2.0$\times10^{-6}$ (-6.1$\times10^{-6}$ / -3.0$\times10^{-6}$)  & 6.8$\times10^{-6}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-6}$ / 1.1$\times10^{-5}$)    & 5.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{18 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{on})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}      & 9.9$\times10^{-4}$ (-8.9$\times10^{-3}$ / 6.9$\times10^{-3}$)   & -9.5$\times10^{-3}$ (-2.4$\times10^{-2}$ / -2.0$\times10^{-3}$) & 1.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{level, Pnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                     & 2.5$\times10^{-4}$ (-7.2$\times10^{-5}$ / 1.5$\times10^{-3}$)   & -4.1$\times10^{-4}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.1$\times10^{-5}$)  & 1.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PR\textsubscript{on})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}                             & -1.7$\times10^{-4}$ (-8.5$\times10^{-3}$ / 7.0$\times10^{-3}$)  & -7.1$\times10^{-3}$ (-2.8$\times10^{-2}$ / -1.7$\times10^{-3}$) & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PR\textsubscript{peak})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}                            & 2.5$\times10^{-4}$ (-3.5$\times10^{-3}$ / 4.4$\times10^{-3}$)   & -5.5$\times10^{-3}$ (-1.5$\times10^{-2}$ / -1.7$\times10^{-4}$) & 8.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.71       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{36 hours before POAF} ($S=30$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{min. vel.})}  \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                     & -7.7$\times10^{-7}$ (-5.7$\times10^{-6}$ / 9.5$\times10^{-6}$)  & 1.9$\times10^{-5}$ (7.9$\times10^{-7}$ / 4.3$\times10^{-5}$)    & 7.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{vel. disp.})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                     & -1.1$\times10^{-6}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-5}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-5}$)  & 2.7$\times10^{-5}$ (2.4$\times10^{-6}$ / 6.2$\times10^{-5}$)    & 9.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.71       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy})} \begin{footnotesize}[$\mu V^2$]\end{footnotesize}                        & -7.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-6.3$\times10^{-9}$ / 7.4$\times10^{-9}$)  & 1.1$\times10^{-8}$ (3.0$\times10^{-9}$ / 2.3$\times10^{-8}$)    & 3.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy norm.})} \begin{footnotesize}[V/s]\end{footnotesize}                  & -1.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-6.9$\times10^{-10}$ / 4.7$\times10^{-10}$)  & 1.1$\times10^{-9}$ (5.1$\times10^{-10}$ / 1.8$\times10^{-9}$)    & 1.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{gauss. error})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}             & -5.1$\times10^{-8}$ (-3.8$\times10^{-6}$ / 2.4$\times10^{-6}$)  & 4.5$\times10^{-6}$ (-7.1$\times10^{-8}$ / 7.9$\times10^{-6}$)   & 4.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}   & 24.0 (16.0 / 28.0)             & 32.0 (24.0 / 37.0)             & 6.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\ \hline

            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{42 hours before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}   & 16.0 (16.0 / 24.0)             & 24.0 (24.0 / 32.0)             & 8.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{off})} \begin{footnotesize}[ms]\end{footnotesize}               & 24.0 (16.0 / 24.0)             & 24.0 (24.0 / 32.0)             & 1.0$\times10^{-2}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}        & 4.1$\times10^{-2}$ (3.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.6$\times10^{-2}$ (4.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.9$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}        & 3.1$\times10^{-2}$ (2.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.2$\times10^{-2}$ (3.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\       
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}       & 2.4$\times10^{-2}$ (1.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 3.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.5$\times10^{-2}$ (3.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\ 

            \hline


            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{48 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{magn.})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                           & -1.4$\times10^{-5}$ (-3.4$\times10^{-5}$ / -8.1$\times10^{-7}$) & 6.7$\times10^{-6}$ (-5.2$\times10^{-6}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-5}$)   & 2.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{rms norm.})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                      & -6.3$\times10^{-7}$ (-1.5$\times10^{-6}$ / -4.1$\times10^{-9}$) & 2.7$\times10^{-7}$ (7.8$\times10^{-8}$ / 6.4$\times10^{-7}$)    & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy})} \begin{footnotesize}[$\mu V^2$]\end{footnotesize}                        & -4.7$\times10^{-9}$ (-1.8$\times10^{-8}$ / 1.3$\times10^{-9}$)  & 2.0$\times10^{-9}$ (1.5$\times10^{-10}$ / 9.2$\times10^{-9}$)    & 7.0$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy norm.})} \begin{footnotesize}[V/s]\end{footnotesize}                  & -4.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-1.2$\times10^{-9}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-11}$)  & 2.1$\times10^{-10}$ (9.6$\times10^{-12}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-9}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\

            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{level, Pnorm})} \begin{footnotesize}[mV]\end{footnotesize}                   & -3.7$\times10^{-3}$ (-7.0$\times10^{-2}$ / -6.6$\times10^{-4}$) & 3.0$\times10^{-5}$ (-2.1$\times10^{-4}$ / 1.8$\times10^{-3}$)   & 7.4$\times10^{-4}$        & 0.86       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.})} \begin{footnotesize}[a.u.]\end{footnotesize}       & 9.3$\times10^{-2}$ (7.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 1.2$\times10^{-1}$)    & 1.4$\times10^{-1}$ (9.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 1.9$\times10^{-1}$)    & 6.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Non-linear variability}

Non-linear CTM was found to significantly differ between POAF patients and controls in all the tested timestamps (Table \ref{table:CTM_results_POAF}). Controls were associated with higher CTM in the great majority of features and timestamps. However, CTM applied over the features P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}, P\textsubscript{fin. dur}, P\textsubscript{magn.}, PQ\textsubscript{level}, PQ\textsubscript{level Pnorm} and P\textsubscript{off amp.} was sometimes higher in POAF patients. Finally, several P-wave time- and morphological metrics were significant after correction for multiple comparisons 1, 12, 18, 42 and 48 hours before the arrhythmia onset, all of them showing higher CTM in controls.


\begin{small}

    \begin{longtable}{llllll}
        \caption[Significant results obtained when using non-linear variability metrics to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.]{Significant results (uncorrected $p<0.01$) obtained when testing the non-linear variability results. The presented values of optimal $\rho$ correspond to the number of multiples of the standard deviation which minimised the \textit{p}-value for the correspondent feature. Results significant after correction for multiple corrections (corrected $p<0.05$) are shaded in grey. The median value (and the first/ third quartiles) of each group are presented (in arbitrary units).}
        \label{table:CTM_results_POAF} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
        \endfoot

        \endlastfoot

        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} (lag$=5$)}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}          & 3.0                      & 0.8944 (0.8751 / 0.9085)            & 0.9089 (0.8996 / 0.9367)        & 2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}         & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)            & 0.9994 (0.9979 / 1.0000)        & 6.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\

        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 4.0                      & 0.9863 (0.9791 / 0.9931)            & 0.9741 (0.9554 / 0.9814)       & 3.1$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.80                           \\

        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}}        & 3.5                   & 0.9849 (0.9677 / 0.9942)            & 0.9529 (0.9303 / 0.9735)        & 5.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9999 / 1.0000)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}}   & 4.0                      & 0.9822 (0.9758 / 0.9884)            & 0.9714 (0.9637 / 0.9767)        & 3.3$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.80                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9906 (0.9822 / 0.9930)            & 0.9754 (0.9658 / 0.9834)        & 3.1$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.85                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. A}}             & 6.0                      & 0.9981 (0.9958 / 0.9990)            & 0.9947 (0.9907 / 0.9977)        & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 4.0                      & 0.9826 (0.9770 / 0.9896)            & 0.9721 (0.9564 / 0.9816)        & 9.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.78                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9776 (0.9687 / 0.9843)            & 0.9647 (0.9560 / 0.9724)        & 4.8$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 5.0                      & 0.9912 (0.9855 / 0.9935)            & 0.9842 (0.9787 / 0.9896)        & 5.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}}          & 4.0                      & 0.9821 (0.9781 / 0.9870)            & 0.9764 (0.9726 / 0.9816)        & 3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{CCI}          & 10.5                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\


        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} (lag$=8$)}   \\ \hline
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 8.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on}}                  & 11.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak}}                & 14.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}   & 9.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 6.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                          \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9952 (0.9892 / 0.9968)            & 0.9884 (0.9756 / 0.9942)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. C}}             & 14.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)            & 0.9991 (0.9986 / 0.9997)        & 7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 3.5                   & 0.9593 (0.9466 / 0.9684)            & 0.9372 (0.9327 / 0.9548)        & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9994 (0.9981 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9998 / 1.0000)        & 2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}    \\ \hline
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur RRnorm}}               & 6.0                     & 0.9995 (0.9988 / 1.0000)            & 0.9982 (0.9957 / 0.9995)        & 4.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}               & 4.5                     & 0.9928 (0.9882 / 0.9966)            & 0.9856 (0.9667 / 0.9913)        & 4.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\          


        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9995 / 1.0000)        & 1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}     \\ \hline
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{energy}}             & 11.5                  & 0.9991 (0.9981 / 0.9997)            & 0.9980 (0.9961 / 0.9987)        & 8.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9941 (0.9895 / 0.9968)            & 0.9911 (0.9816 / 0.9922)        & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9993 (0.9976 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} (lag$=4$)}    \\ \hline


        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}                 & 9.5                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 2.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.64                           \\

        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on}}                  & 7.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 7.6$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.71                           \\


        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. W}}             & 20.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 9.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 2.5                   & 0.9210 (0.8766 / 0.9576)            & 0.8810 (0.8358 / 0.9132)        & 7.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 2.0                      & 0.8111 (0.7547 / 0.8485)            & 0.7089 (0.6585 / 0.7424)        & 1.5$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.84                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 2.0                      & 0.7889 (0.7472 / 0.8466)            & 0.6877 (0.6503 / 0.7236)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{off amp.}}           & 8.0                      & 0.9971 (0.9952 / 0.9986)            & 0.9992 (0.9980 / 1.0000)        & 2.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 5.5                   & 0.9988 (0.9962 / 0.9995)            & 0.9997 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
        \textbf{WI$_t$}                        & 2.5                   & 0.8301 (0.8163 / 0.8425)            & 0.8083 (0.8008 / 0.8246)        & 3.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76         \\ \hline                 
    \end{longtable}

\end{small}

















\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the code in form of an MWE here (and not elsewhere).

Comment: You can use the `\FloatBarrier` from package `placeins`, just before `\subsubsection{Non-linear variability} and allow the table to be inserted also at the bottom of pages. Unrelated: don't use `\resizebox` with tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Better play with the separation between columns and the font size in the table.

Comment: You put the table before the longtable, but it floats below it. If you were to put the table below the longtable, you will have the desired ordering. I can't refrain from asking if you are sure that you want to keep the `\resizebox` and `small` stuff. I personally like documents in which the author restrict the content to its absolutely necessary minimum and keeps the font size universal better.

Comment: But the reference to the normal table comes firstly than the reference to the longtable :\
About resizebox, I know, but I really had to use it!

Comment: Any idea how to put the normal table to appear first?

Comment: You never have to use `\resizebox` on a table there is always a better way.

Comment: as Bernard already said you can use `\FloatBarrier` (or more simply `\clearpage`) to stop the float floating past the longtable.

Comment: Ups, my apologies. I have now tried it and it works, but it causes a big blank space in my page :s

Comment: An opportunity to write some more words to fill the space:-) The table is too large to fit in the space remaining on that section (and you make it larger with arraystretch) so if you stop it floating later in the document a space is the only option unless you re-arrange the text or make that one a longtable too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This avoids the floats going out of order and avoids scaling tables

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
%% To allow tables collumns auto newline
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}    % Beautiful simple tables
\usepackage{paralist}    % To enable customizble enumerates
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox,tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}



\subsubsection{Linear variability}

Significant results obtained when testing the linear variability metrics are presented in Table \ref{table:linear_var_POAF_results}. Briefly, the variability in both time and morphological features were significantly different between POAF and controls far away from the arrhythmia (at least 18 hours away), while only variability in P-wave time features were significant as the arrhythmia onset got closer. The POAF group had higher median variability for all the presented timestamps, and showed increasing variability (slope) in all timestamps except 18 hours before the arrhythmia onset. In contrast, controls presented decreasing variability in the majority of variability regression slope results. The PQ interval (duration and level) was the only feature which had metrics significant after correction for multiple comparisons at 6 and 48 hours before the arrhythmia onset.

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption[Significant results obtained when using linear variability metrics to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.]{Significant results (uncorrected $p<0.01$) obtained when using the linear variability metrics. Results significant after correction for multiple corrections (corrected $p<0.05$) are shaded in grey. The median value (and the first/ third quartiles) of each group are presented.}
    \label{table:linear_var_POAF_results}
    \tiny
   \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\bfdefault{b}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

        \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
            \hline
            \textbf{Metrics}                                                    & \textbf{Controls}                 & \textbf{POAF}                    & \textbf{P-value} & \textbf{AUC} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})}  [a.u.]        & 4.8$\times10^{-2}$ (4.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.7$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.8$\times10^{-2}$ (5.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 7.6$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\

            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} [a.u.]       & 1.5$\times10^{-2}$ (1.2$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.2$\times10^{-2}$ (2.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm})} [a.u.] & 5.5$\times10^{-2}$ (4.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.2$\times10^{-2}$ (5.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} [a.u.]        & 5.1$\times10^{-2}$ (4.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.6$\times10^{-2}$ (5.7$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 1.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} [a.u.]       & 4.0$\times10^{-2}$ (3.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.5$\times10^{-2}$ (4.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 7.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} [a.u.]      & 1.7$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 3.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.5$\times10^{-2}$ (2.2$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.6$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} [a.u.]      & 1.7$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.8$\times10^{-2}$ (1.9$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 8.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                            \\ \hline  
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} [ms]   & 24.0 (16.0 / 30.0)             & 28.0 (24.0 / 37.0)             & 5.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm})} [a.u.] & 5.9$\times10^{-2}$ (5.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.1$\times10^{-2}$ (6.1$\times10^{-2}$ / 9.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on})} [ms]                & 38.0 (32.0 / 44.0)             & 44.0 (36.0 / 58.0)             & 5.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\

            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} [a.u.]        & 5.6$\times10^{-2}$ (4.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.9$\times10^{-2}$ (6.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 9.0$\times10^{-2}$)    & 2.9$\times10^{-4}$        & 0.80       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak})} [ms]             & 8.0 (8.0 / 12.0)               & 16.0 (11.0 / 21.0)             & 1.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} [a.u.]       & 4.8$\times10^{-2}$ (3.7$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.9$\times10^{-2}$ (4.8$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.7$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm})} [a.u.]     & 1.5$\times10^{-2}$ (1.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 2.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.3$\times10^{-2}$ (1.9$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.5$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(Q\textsubscript{on amp.})} [mV]                       & -2.0$\times10^{-6}$ (-6.1$\times10^{-6}$ / -3.0$\times10^{-6}$)  & 6.8$\times10^{-6}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-6}$ / 1.1$\times10^{-5}$)    & 5.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{18 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{on})} [ms]      & 9.9$\times10^{-4}$ (-8.9$\times10^{-3}$ / 6.9$\times10^{-3}$)   & -9.5$\times10^{-3}$ (-2.4$\times10^{-2}$ / -2.0$\times10^{-3}$) & 1.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{level, Pnorm})} [mV]                     & 2.5$\times10^{-4}$ (-7.2$\times10^{-5}$ / 1.5$\times10^{-3}$)   & -4.1$\times10^{-4}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-2}$ / 8.1$\times10^{-5}$)  & 1.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PR\textsubscript{on})} [ms]                             & -1.7$\times10^{-4}$ (-8.5$\times10^{-3}$ / 7.0$\times10^{-3}$)  & -7.1$\times10^{-3}$ (-2.8$\times10^{-2}$ / -1.7$\times10^{-3}$) & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PR\textsubscript{peak})} [ms]                            & 2.5$\times10^{-4}$ (-3.5$\times10^{-3}$ / 4.4$\times10^{-3}$)   & -5.5$\times10^{-3}$ (-1.5$\times10^{-2}$ / -1.7$\times10^{-4}$) & 8.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.71       \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{36 hours before POAF} ($S=30$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{min. vel.})}  [mV]                     & -7.7$\times10^{-7}$ (-5.7$\times10^{-6}$ / 9.5$\times10^{-6}$)  & 1.9$\times10^{-5}$ (7.9$\times10^{-7}$ / 4.3$\times10^{-5}$)    & 7.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{vel. disp.})} [mV]                     & -1.1$\times10^{-6}$ (-1.1$\times10^{-5}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-5}$)  & 2.7$\times10^{-5}$ (2.4$\times10^{-6}$ / 6.2$\times10^{-5}$)    & 9.2$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.71       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy})} [$\mu V^2$]                        & -7.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-6.3$\times10^{-9}$ / 7.4$\times10^{-9}$)  & 1.1$\times10^{-8}$ (3.0$\times10^{-9}$ / 2.3$\times10^{-8}$)    & 3.4$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy norm.})} [V/s]                  & -1.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-6.9$\times10^{-10}$ / 4.7$\times10^{-10}$)  & 1.1$\times10^{-9}$ (5.1$\times10^{-10}$ / 1.8$\times10^{-9}$)    & 1.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{gauss. error})} [a.u.]             & -5.1$\times10^{-8}$ (-3.8$\times10^{-6}$ / 2.4$\times10^{-6}$)  & 4.5$\times10^{-6}$ (-7.1$\times10^{-8}$ / 7.9$\times10^{-6}$)   & 4.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} [ms]   & 24.0 (16.0 / 28.0)             & 32.0 (24.0 / 37.0)             & 6.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\ \hline

            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{42 hours before POAF} ($S=5$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{fin. dur.})} [ms]   & 16.0 (16.0 / 24.0)             & 24.0 (24.0 / 32.0)             & 8.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{off})} [ms]               & 24.0 (16.0 / 24.0)             & 24.0 (24.0 / 32.0)             & 1.0$\times10^{-2}$        & 0.72       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm})} [a.u.]        & 4.1$\times10^{-2}$ (3.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.4$\times10^{-2}$)    & 5.6$\times10^{-2}$ (4.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 6.9$\times10^{-2}$)    & 6.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm})} [a.u.]        & 3.1$\times10^{-2}$ (2.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.2$\times10^{-2}$ (3.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 5.2$\times10^{-2}$)    & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.75       \\       
            \textbf{\textit{m}(PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm})} [a.u.]       & 2.4$\times10^{-2}$ (1.4$\times10^{-2}$ / 3.5$\times10^{-2}$)    & 3.5$\times10^{-2}$ (3.0$\times10^{-2}$ / 4.3$\times10^{-2}$)    & 7.7$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\ 

            \hline


            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{48 hours before POAF} ($S=10$)}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{magn.})} [mV]                           & -1.4$\times10^{-5}$ (-3.4$\times10^{-5}$ / -8.1$\times10^{-7}$) & 6.7$\times10^{-6}$ (-5.2$\times10^{-6}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-5}$)   & 2.1$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.78       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{rms norm.})} [mV]                      & -6.3$\times10^{-7}$ (-1.5$\times10^{-6}$ / -4.1$\times10^{-9}$) & 2.7$\times10^{-7}$ (7.8$\times10^{-8}$ / 6.4$\times10^{-7}$)    & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.73       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy})} [$\mu V^2$]                        & -4.7$\times10^{-9}$ (-1.8$\times10^{-8}$ / 1.3$\times10^{-9}$)  & 2.0$\times10^{-9}$ (1.5$\times10^{-10}$ / 9.2$\times10^{-9}$)    & 7.0$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(P\textsubscript{energy norm.})} [V/s]                  & -4.1$\times10^{-10}$ (-1.2$\times10^{-9}$ / 4.1$\times10^{-11}$)  & 2.1$\times10^{-10}$ (9.6$\times10^{-12}$ / 1.6$\times10^{-9}$)    & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.76       \\

            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$(PQ\textsubscript{level, Pnorm})} [mV]                   & -3.7$\times10^{-3}$ (-7.0$\times10^{-2}$ / -6.6$\times10^{-4}$) & 3.0$\times10^{-5}$ (-2.1$\times10^{-4}$ / 1.8$\times10^{-3}$)   & 7.4$\times10^{-4}$        & 0.86       \\
            \textbf{\textit{m}(P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.})} [a.u.]       & 9.3$\times10^{-2}$ (7.3$\times10^{-2}$ / 1.2$\times10^{-1}$)    & 1.4$\times10^{-1}$ (9.6$\times10^{-2}$ / 1.9$\times10^{-1}$)    & 6.6$\times10^{-3}$        & 0.74       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\subsubsection{Non-linear variability}

Non-linear CTM was found to significantly differ between POAF patients and controls in all the tested timestamps (Table \ref{table:CTM_results_POAF}). Controls were associated with higher CTM in the great majority of features and timestamps. However, CTM applied over the features P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}, P\textsubscript{fin. dur}, P\textsubscript{magn.}, PQ\textsubscript{level}, PQ\textsubscript{level Pnorm} and P\textsubscript{off amp.} was sometimes higher in POAF patients. Finally, several P-wave time- and morphological metrics were significant after correction for multiple comparisons 1, 12, 18, 42 and 48 hours before the arrhythmia onset, all of them showing higher CTM in controls.


\begin{footnotesize}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}

    \begin{longtable}{@{}llllll@{}}
        \caption[Significant results obtained when using non-linear variability metrics to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.]{Significant results (uncorrected $p<0.01$) obtained when testing the non-linear variability results. The presented values of optimal $\rho$ correspond to the number of multiples of the standard deviation which minimised the \textit{p}-value for the correspondent feature. Results significant after correction for multiple corrections (corrected $p<0.05$) are shaded in grey. The median value (and the first/ third quartiles) of each group are presented (in arbitrary units).}
        \label{table:CTM_results_POAF} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
        \endfoot

        \endlastfoot

        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} (lag$=5$)}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}          & 3.0                      & 0.8944 (0.8751 / 0.9085)            & 0.9089 (0.8996 / 0.9367)        & 2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}         & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)            & 0.9994 (0.9979 / 1.0000)        & 6.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\

        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 4.0                      & 0.9863 (0.9791 / 0.9931)            & 0.9741 (0.9554 / 0.9814)       & 3.1$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.80                           \\

        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}}        & 3.5                   & 0.9849 (0.9677 / 0.9942)            & 0.9529 (0.9303 / 0.9735)        & 5.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9999 / 1.0000)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}}   & 4.0                      & 0.9822 (0.9758 / 0.9884)            & 0.9714 (0.9637 / 0.9767)        & 3.3$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.80                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9906 (0.9822 / 0.9930)            & 0.9754 (0.9658 / 0.9834)        & 3.1$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.85                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. A}}             & 6.0                      & 0.9981 (0.9958 / 0.9990)            & 0.9947 (0.9907 / 0.9977)        & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 4.0                      & 0.9826 (0.9770 / 0.9896)            & 0.9721 (0.9564 / 0.9816)        & 9.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.78                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9776 (0.9687 / 0.9843)            & 0.9647 (0.9560 / 0.9724)        & 4.8$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 5.0                      & 0.9912 (0.9855 / 0.9935)            & 0.9842 (0.9787 / 0.9896)        & 5.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}}          & 4.0                      & 0.9821 (0.9781 / 0.9870)            & 0.9764 (0.9726 / 0.9816)        & 3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{CCI}          & 10.5                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\


        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} (lag$=8$)}   \\ \hline
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 8.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on}}                  & 11.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak}}                & 14.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}   & 9.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 6.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                          \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9952 (0.9892 / 0.9968)            & 0.9884 (0.9756 / 0.9942)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. C}}             & 14.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)            & 0.9991 (0.9986 / 0.9997)        & 7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 3.5                   & 0.9593 (0.9466 / 0.9684)            & 0.9372 (0.9327 / 0.9548)        & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9994 (0.9981 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9998 / 1.0000)        & 2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}    \\ \hline
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur RRnorm}}               & 6.0                     & 0.9995 (0.9988 / 1.0000)            & 0.9982 (0.9957 / 0.9995)        & 4.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
        \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}               & 4.5                     & 0.9928 (0.9882 / 0.9966)            & 0.9856 (0.9667 / 0.9913)        & 4.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\          


        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9995 / 1.0000)        & 1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}     \\ \hline
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{energy}}             & 11.5                  & 0.9991 (0.9981 / 0.9997)            & 0.9980 (0.9961 / 0.9987)        & 8.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9941 (0.9895 / 0.9968)            & 0.9911 (0.9816 / 0.9922)        & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9993 (0.9976 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} (lag$=4$)}    \\ \hline


        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.65                           \\
        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}                 & 9.5                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 2.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.64                           \\

        \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on}}                  & 7.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 7.6$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.71                           \\


        \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. W}}             & 20.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 9.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 2.5                   & 0.9210 (0.8766 / 0.9576)            & 0.8810 (0.8358 / 0.9132)        & 7.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 2.0                      & 0.8111 (0.7547 / 0.8485)            & 0.7089 (0.6585 / 0.7424)        & 1.5$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.84                           \\

        \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 2.0                      & 0.7889 (0.7472 / 0.8466)            & 0.6877 (0.6503 / 0.7236)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{off amp.}}           & 8.0                      & 0.9971 (0.9952 / 0.9986)            & 0.9992 (0.9980 / 1.0000)        & 2.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
        \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 5.5                   & 0.9988 (0.9962 / 0.9995)            & 0.9997 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
        \textbf{WI$_t$}                        & 2.5                   & 0.8301 (0.8163 / 0.8425)            & 0.8083 (0.8008 / 0.8246)        & 3.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76         \\ \hline                 
    \end{longtable}

\end{footnotesize}

















\end{document}
```